Unable to connect Microsoft SQL Server database with superset
I am using this command:
mssql+pyodbc://root:Welcome@DESKTOP-RB7C835\SQLEXPRESS:1433/CM33_LDV
I have tried everything but unable to connect database with superset.
I am trying to connect Microsoft SQL Server database to superset
